# How do I set the width of an Tkinter Entry widget in pixels?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, width, tkinter-entry

I noticed that the **width** argument for the Tkinter entry widget is in characters, not pixels.

Is it possible to adjust the width in pixels?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot specify the width in pixels using the '-width' option, but there are ways to accomplish the same thing. For example, you could pack an entry in a frame that has no border, turn off geometry propagation on the frame, then set the width of the frame in pixels.

Comment: @CoolCloud: if you're referring to a couple of typos, thanks for letting me know. I've fixed them.

Answer (score 22):

You can also use the Place geometry manager:

```
entry.place(x=10, y=10, width=100) #width in pixels
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "ipadx" and "ipady" while packing the "Entry" widget.

You can also use it with "grid".

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk

e = tk.Entry()
e.pack(ipadx=100, ipady=15)

tk.mainloop()
```