# tkinter python entry height

Tags: python, tkinter, height, tkinter-entry

I'm making a simple app just to practice python in which I want to write text as if it were Notepad. However, I can't make my entry bigger. I'm using tkinter for this. Does anybody know how to make the height of an entry bigger?

I tried something like this:

```
f = Frame()
f.pack()
e = Entry(f,textvariable=1,height=20)
e.pack()
```

I know this doesn't work because there isn't a property of "height". However, I see that there is a width property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the width of an Tkinter Entry widget in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881010/how-do-i-set-the-width-of-an-tkinter-entry-widget-in-pixels)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also change it by changing the font size :

```
Entry(
root,
font=("default", 40 or 20 whatever )

)
```

Answer (score 31):

It sounds like you are looking for [`tkinter.Text`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023803/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm), which allows you to adjust both the height and width of the widget. Below is a simple script to demonstrate:

```
from tkinter import Text, Tk

r = Tk()
r.geometry("400x400")

t = Text(r, height=20, width=40)
t.pack()

r.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 17):

Another way would be to increase the internal padding by adding this in the pack method:

```
...
e = Entry(f,textvariable=1,height=20)
e.pack(ipady=3)
...
```

for instance. This worked for me for an 'Entry' and it also works with .grid()

Comment: This should be the answer to this question. The accepted answer(i.e. @iCodez's answer) is an alternative.

Comment: @SunBear.  I disagree, re-read the question and not the code snippet.

Comment: `tk.Entry()` does not have a `height` parameter to be set

Comment: Thanks! This is technically not the answer to this question, but it did answer the question I was having. :)

Answer (score 8):

Actually it's very easy. You don't need to set `height` in `Entry()`, but in `place()`.
for example:

```
from tkinter import Entry, Tk

window = Tk()
t = Entry(window)
t.place(width=150,height=50)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

url = Label(root,text="Enter Url")
url.grid(row=0,padx=10,pady=10)

entry_url = Entry(root,width="50")
entry_url.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=10,ipady=3)

root.geometry("600x300+150+150")

root.mainloop()
```

**learn more follow this** [github](https://github.com/harishkumawat2610)

output image [this is output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Sdc.png)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and doesn't create an experience similar to notepad where you can enter multiple lines of text and use carriage returns.  Your solution changes the appearance of tk.entry which is a single line and meant for user input. The OP needed a solution where you have a text editor experience.

Answer (score 3):

To change an entry widget's size,  you have to change it's font to a larger font.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

large_font = ('Verdana',30)
small_font = ('Verdana',10)

root = tk.Tk()

entry1Var = tk.StringVar(value='Large Font!')
entry1 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=entry1Var,font=large_font)
entry1.pack()    

entry2Var = tk.StringVar(value='Small Font!')
entry2 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=entry2Var,font=small_font)
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of the entry widget.
To do so you can write:

```py
entry_box.place(height=40, width=100)
```

Change the value according to your needs! 
IT WORKS !

Answer (score 0):

By using the .place(width= , height= ) method, you can adjust the size of the entry. Another Method is to change the font of the text, but that limits your ability to change the font.

.place() method:

```
textbox.place(width= (Your desired width) ,height= (Your desired height))
```

Font Method:

```
textbox = Entry(root, font=("default", (Your font size))
```

Hope this helps!