# tkinter Entry height

Tags: python, tkinter, height, tkinter-entry

I tried

```
textEntry = Entry(root, width=115, textvariable=text, height=12)
```

but I got an error invloving the height.

Then I tried using the `Text` widget:

```
textEntry = Text(root, width=115, textvariable=text, height=12)
```

but I got an error involving `textvariable=text`

Any way I could adjust the height of the `Entry` or the variable of the `Text`?

Comment: You will get errors if you just guess what arguments a method accepts, see for example http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Comment: why do you need to use a variable with the text widget?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the width of an Tkinter Entry widget in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881010/how-do-i-set-the-width-of-an-tkinter-entry-widget-in-pixels)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tkinter python entry height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501606/tkinter-python-entry-height)

Answer (score 5):

To change an entry widget's size you have to change its font to a larger one.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

large_font = ('Verdana',30)
small_font = ('Verdana',10)

root = tk.Tk()

entry1Var = tk.StringVar(value='Large Font!')
entry1 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=entry1Var,font=large_font)
entry1.pack()    

entry2Var = tk.StringVar(value='Small Font!')
entry2 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=entry2Var,font=small_font)
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't have to, you just have to invoke the ```-height``` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to set the height of an Entry widget,and no, there is no way to use a variable with the text widget.

If you need a widget that allows you to enter more than one line of text your only option is a `Text` widget, and there's simply no reason to associate a variable with the widget because a text widget can contain more than just characters (images, embedded widgets, styling information)

Answer (score 1):

You can set height of an Entry by using ipady. Here's an example :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() # make window

entry = Entry() # make entry object
entry.grid(ipady=5) # display and set height of Entry object

root.mainloop() # run the code
```

sidenote = You cannot type multiple lines in an Entry. If thats what you want, you will have to use the Text widget.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having the same problem as in the following link, there is an answer posted there:
[tkinter python entry height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501606/tkinter-python-entry-height)

Comment: If you think it is a duplicate, flag it as such.  If you click the `flag` link, there is `should be closed`.  If you click that, you will see `Duplicate of`.  If you click that, paste the link into the bar.